# Subract day from iso8601 date string in elisp

Tags: time, emacs

How would I use emacs lisp to go from `"2020-06-01"` to `"2020-05-31"`?

I thought this would work but obviously not

```lisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" (time-subtract (date-to-time "2020-06-01") (days-to-time 1)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 1999-12-30
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I type the code you give, I get the result you expect.

Comment: Woah...really @jthulu? that's a direct copy-paste from my org document. Same thing when I `C-x C-e` This is on emacs 28

Comment: maybe you forgot to update the cell?

Comment: Hmm...nope, even just tried rebooting and running in a scratch buffer. I'm...not even sure where to start debugging that

Comment: Emacs 28 has problems in `date-to-time`, see [bug 52209](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=52209).

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you wrote. (Evaluated using `C-c C-c`)

```
#+begin_src elisp
  (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" (time-subtract (date-to-time "2020-06-01") (days-to-time 1)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 2020-05-31
```

It works fine.

Comment: what version of emacs are you on? I'm 28.2 on macos

Comment: 29.0.50 on linux ubuntu

Comment: I wonder if this is bizarely a macos thing. will have to test on linux tonight